# Android ArrayAdapter with multiple objects?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Can I set an ArrayAdapter < Object > or ArrayAdapter < String > with multiple objects? I have a ListView Item with an Icon and a TextView. I can use this to set the TextView names:

```
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item,
            mDrawerItems));
```

But I also want to assign an Icon to each ImageView for each ListView Item. I have got an `int[]` with all Drawable Icon References, how can I pass this to the Adapter?

The ImageView ID is: `android:id="@android:id/icon1"`

The TextView ID is: `android:id="@android:id/text1"`

Comment: What you need is a custom adapter. You can subclass `BaseAdapter` for that. Tutorial: [Android: Custom ListView with Image and Text using BaseAdapter](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a custom adapter, trying to take shortcuts :P Thank you I will do that now. Post an official answer and I'll accept it :) thanks!

Comment: You'll see that once you follow the tutorial I suggested, you'll be writing custom adapters on the fly. There's nothing to them really. It'll make your life easier. About posting an answer: What I gave you was a suggestion, not an answer. You can `upvote` the comment to indicate that it helped you.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I can't upvote until 15 reputation. I'm a newbie lol But yeah, I'll learn to code custom adapters. Definitely the more strategic option :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SimpleAdapter` with `Map` for data. 
More:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html

Comment: This looks like a viable option :) and an alternative to a custom adapter. I'll give this a go